# ListManipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, insert

I changed the list a bit, maybe this really what I want. Please I need some suggestions.

I wanted to combine this two list,

```
list1 = {{{a1,a2}, {b1,b2}, {c1,c2}, {d1,d2}}, {{a4,a5}, {b4, b5}, {c4,c5},{d4,d5}}};

list2 = {{a3, b3, c3, d3}, {a6, b6, c6, d6}};
```

To look like this:

```
output= {{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3},{d1,d2,d3}}, {{a4,a5,a6},{b4,b5,b6},{c4,c5,c6},{d4,d5,d6}};
```

What I am going to do?

Thank you very much